# How do I resize elements in the graphical version of XML?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

This is going to seem like such a stupid question but I am trying to resize an image I added to the graphical layout of my XML file. I can drag it around but it won't let me resize it.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: I personally suggest avoid using the designer, it will make your layout display differently on different phone sizes, always use xml to manually write your layout to be sure what exactly is happening, eclipse designer is not the best

Comment: Thanks, I'm still new to eclipse and thought it was odd I couldn't resize. Will keep this in mind

Comment: you can switch to the xml of your layout and can set android:layout_width and android:layout_height to your likings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are unable to resize in `graphical layout` then you can resize in `XML` file.

You can use `Height`, `Width` and `Weight` parameters to resize..

Remove `Wrap_content` kind or words and provide values like `50dip`

hope this helps.

Comment: yeah this one is prefered